# Why select a new value in repository combobox but it cannot be fetched in the gridcontrol?

Tags: c#, combobox, repository, devexpress, gridcontrol

Hi I have a gridcontrol, which includes three columns: column1, column2 and column 3. Column2 and Column3 are repository comboBox1 and repository comboBox2: repcomboBox 1 has a data source of string type list and repcomboBox2 has a data source of int type list.

My grid control also has a data source.

I hope to implement the following function: when stringA is selected in repcomboBox1, the value in repcomboBox2 will be default to intA.

I try the following code:

```
    private void repoCombo1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = gridControl1.FocusedView as GridView;
        string format = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("field2Name").ToString();
        if (format.Equals(stringA))
        {
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, view.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("field3Name"), intA);
        }
    }
```

For example, if in rowX the current value in repcomboBox1 is stringB, I selected stringA instead of stringB, I debug into the code and find " string format = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("field2Name").ToString();" set format as "stringB" other than "stringA" which I expect. How could I get the newly selected value in the repository comboBox? Why it doesn't change? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following code for this purpose:

```
object value = (sender as BaseEdit).EditValue;
if(value != null)
  string format = value.ToString();        
  if (format.Equals(stringA))        {            
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, view.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("field3Name"), intA);
```